# How I can get an Image height and divide it by 2 using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I need to set height of an image to half using j query, So that on click it expands to auto height, How is this possinble please guide.
Currently I used a class with property height: 202px and on click I change that class with another one containing height: auto property, But this does not work fine on responsive views.
So I need to divide the height:auto property by 2, How can i do this with j query, Please guide me with example
    Here is my css

```
                 .how-we-do .expand-image {
    height: auto 
}
.how-we-do .expand-image2 {
height:202px ;
}
```

Here is my jquery code

```
       $('.expand-image').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('expand-image');
            $(this).addClass('expand-image2');
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.height()` to half the height of an on-screen image. `.height()` takes a function, the second parameter of which will be the current height of the element.

Return this value halved and you have what you need:

```
$('img').height(function(_,v){ return v/2; });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8hu84oak/1/)

Comment: Why would you use a function instead of just grabbing the value yourself as in my answer?

Comment: fair enough, nice explanation. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Quickfix:

```
$('img').height() / 2
```

Comment: You haven't set the `img`'s height

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var cheight = $('.parendiv').innerHeight();

                $('img').css({
                    'height' : cheight + 20
                });
```

Comment: `parentdiv`? Why `+ 20`? I can't make sense of this answer.

Comment: this is example only for changing the height of img

Comment: It's not relevant though.